# Copy website including images and styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a chrome extension, that allows me to copy the DOM of a webite and upload it to a server for analysis (dont worry, nothing illegal). Doing so does not provide the images or css scripts of the page.

Is there an "easy way" to get transfer the images and scripts that are used in the DOM as well? Currently I am using `document.all[0].outerHTML` for reading the HTML itself.

Comment: Look for `.css` files in the header and goto those address and get the style?

Comment: @Jay Currently, I only get relative paths in my DOM, so on the server-side there is no way of doing this.

Comment: File > Save Page As > Webpage, Complete?

Comment: @Moob Can I do this using the chrome extension, uploading it automatically to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite nice way to upload the images in one package with the HTML / DOM:

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/891624), I had a very easy way to convert almost any image in Base64. I replaced the `src` attribute of the `img` tag using jQuery and uploaded the complete DOM. Like that all the images are already implemented.